# UITextView scroll only horizontally

Tags: iphone, scroll, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have one line of text that is too long to be displayed in one single line in a `UILabel`, so I switched to a `UITextView`. I wanted to display that text still in one line, and be able to scroll horizontally, but instead, the `UITextView` will wrap the text into multiple lines, and allow me to scroll vertically. So, for the text "This is a very very long line", instead of displaying it like "This is a ", and then if scrolled horizontally, it would display the rest of it, it actually displays it like "This is a \n very very long \n line". How can I get the behavior I want?

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that behavior you should place the label inside a scrollview. That's the only way you'll be able to scroll a label in any direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using Merrimack's advice, this worked for me:

```
self.dishNameLabel.text = @"Here is some very longgggg text to test with";
float width = ceil([self.dishNameLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"WorkSans-SemiBold" size:15.0]}].width);
self.dishNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.dishNameLabel.frame.origin.x, self.dishNameLabel.frame.origin.y, width, self.dishNameLabel.frame.size.height);
self.dishNameScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( width, self.dishNameScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Of course, you will have to replace your text and font with your respective specs